# horizontal and vertical dash lines in between homogeneous transformation matrix

Tags: matrices

i am new to latex and how do O write this in latex please? I just know how to write simple  matrices. This matix includes both horizontal and vertical dash lines and lower row has four columns. `R(q)` is 3x3 matrix and `p(q)` is a 3x1 matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arydshln` package provides the command `\hdashline` (a generalization of `\hline`) and the intercolumn separator type `:` (a generalization of `|`). I suggest you use them in conjunction with nested `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln} % load *after* 'array'

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\left[\begin{array}{@{}c:c@{}}
 R(q)          & p(q) \\ \hdashline
 \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}} 
     0 & 0 & 0
 \end{array}  & 1 
\end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```